# Why is the server still being mapped - SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, alternate-access-mapping, uls

So I am troubleshooting an error and trying to find where the Mapping URI message is getting the server/host information from, within the ULS logs it shows:

Mapping URI from 'https://portal.xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:443/staff/Pages/ssDuties.aspx' to 'https://other.xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/staff/Pages/ssDuties.aspx'

I have removed the 'other' server/host entry from the alternate access mappings, and I'm wondering why it is still being mapped, is it located somewhere else in CA?

We are running SP2013 on-premise.

Thanks

Comment: Is the Https://Portal.xxx...... URL extended to the HTTPS://other.xxx...... URL? This could cause what you are seeing. If this is the case you will just need to unextend the webapp.

Comment: Sorry but I am not exactly sure what you mean, could you expand on that please Josh.